# how to fetch all records of MS ACCESS data in ASP .NET one by one

Tags: asp.net, ms-access-2007

I am working with ASP .NET and MS ACCESS to implement an online quiz system i want to fetch next question and their options from database but the button NEXT fired only once..i can fetch only first row of data using this code..i want to fetch every row from databse

```
If inc < ds.Tables("Q_A").Rows.Count / 2 - 1 Then
        inc = inc + 1
        NavigateRecords()

    Else
        MsgBox("Last Question")
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub NavigateRecords()

    Try
        lblQuestion.Text = ds.Tables("Q_A").Rows(inc).Item(0).ToString()
        rbtn1.Text = ds.Tables("Q_A").Rows(inc).Item(1).ToString()
        rbtn2.Text = ds.Tables("Q_A").Rows(inc).Item(2).ToString()
        rbtn3.Text = ds.Tables("Q_A").Rows(inc).Item(3).ToString()
        rbtn4.Text = ds.Tables("Q_A").Rows(inc).Item(4).ToString()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

same code is working fine with windows form application in vb .net

Comment: What is `ds`? How are you getting daa from the datavase?

Comment: my data set is Try

            Dim M As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Q_A ", con)
            M.Fill(ds, "Q_A")

            maxRows = ds.Tables("Q_A").Rows.Count


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try

Comment: Please update your question (non-trivial code in comments is unreadable).